# XSLT not passing via javascript function

Tags: xslt-list-view-web-part

I'm using a DFWP and customising to send values to javascript function.

I've managed to pass certain types of variables from XSLT to Javascript using the below code.

```
<a><xsl:attribute name="href">#</xsl:attribute><xsl:attribute name="onClick">javascript:portal_openModalDialog("<xsl:value-of select='@ows_Title' />","<xsl:value-of select='@ows_ID' />")</xsl:attribute>test</a>
```

This works fine but when  try to exchange `ows_ID` for `ows_Description` (Multiline field) nothing happens (function does not appear to work).

I tried escaping using `disable-output-escaping` but still nothing works.

When I print out to screen I can see the value of  `xsl:value-of select="@ows_Description"` with and without the `disable-output-escaping`.

I've copied `@ows_Description` to a variable and then attempted to pass the variable instead but as previously the function doesnt work.

Finally I would also like to truncate the `ows_Description`.

UPDATE:
Think it might help to show output of @ows_Description (without disable-output-escaping)

```
<div class="ExternalClassB01973441A78460F8B02CD3603EF4C07"><p>​<span class="st">The James Dyson <strong>Award</strong> is an international design <strong>award</strong> that celebrates, encourages and inspires the next generation of design engineers. The <strong>Award</strong> is open ...</span></p></div>
```

Below is how it appears after changing the code as suggested (SPD has change automatically after save)

```
<a><xsl:attribute name="href">#</xsl:attribute><xsl:attribute name="onClick">javascript:portal_openModalDialog("<xsl:value-of select='@ows_Title' />","translate('<xsl:value-of select='@ows_Description' />&apos;,&apos;
```

','')")
test

Answer (score 0):

New line characters might be causing this problem. Try removing those character using `translate` function and then pass it to JavaScript.

Something like

```
javascript:portal_openModalDialog("<xsl:value-of select='@ows_Title' />","translate('<xsl:value-of select='@ows_Description' />','&#xD;&#xA;','')")
```

Comment: Tried the above line but SPD changes the last few characters to &apos; and same problem persists.

Comment: @user32056 can you update the question with how it now appear in SPD?